From a theistic epistemological perspective, how does one distinguish between mundane events and divinely orchestrated ones?
I'm agnostic, but I have several friends and acquaintances who are theists, and some have tried to persuade me toward their beliefs. One thing I find difficult to grasp is their epistemology—how they determine that God is interacting with them or that certain events are divine interventions rather than just ordinary occurrences.
To be fair, I can understand the significant effort Christian apologists put into defending events like the resurrection as examples of divine intervention. Such events, if true, would indeed defy our understanding of physics, biology, and medicine, so it intuitively makes sense to consider them as potential examples of divine action. However, when it comes to more everyday occurrences, I find it harder to understand the theistic mindset.
From a theistic epistemological perspective, how does one distinguish between mundane events and divinely orchestrated ones? For instance, if the wind moves the curtains in my apartment, would that be seen as a purely mundane event without deeper meaning, or could there be grounds to interpret it as a divine message or intervention?

The Catholic Church has a rigorous and transparent process for the investigation of miracles. https://dornsife.usc.edu/news/stories/what-is-a-miracle/#:~:text=Separately%2C%20a%20medical%20board%20of,a%20simple%20majority%20was%20needed.

Just as with sense perception, the judgment of divine involvement is usually made on the totality of context accompanying the event. For example, whether it is physically impossible or statistically improbable, whether it appears to "answer a prayer" or is accompanied by attention-focusing religious experience. On phenomenology of religious experience of the mundane see SEP, Phenomenology of  Religion.

If "divine orchestrated events" are according to nature laws, they are events.  If not, they are miracles... and there are no miracles

@MauroALLEGRANZA How does one go about showing there are no miracles?

As a Christian myself, I'll take a stab at this from a personal and biblical viewpoint.  Based on the question, I am not referring to epistemology relating to knowing that God exists, or that Jesus Christ rose from the dead, for example (e.g., apologetic discussions); but rather, assuming a person already believes in God, how to distinguish His working in day-to-day life from mundane events.  Here's the way I see it as a Christian trying to follow the Bible, and with that preface...
First, biblically, the written word of God serves as an absolute epistemological guardrail.  In other words, if anything goes against the written Bible, biblically, a Christian ought to reject it, no matter how miraculous or reasonable it may seem.  For example, in Matthew 24:24, Jesus warns, "For there shall arise false Christs, and false prophets, and shall shew great signs and wonders; insomuch that, if it were possible, they shall deceive the very elect."  And in Revelation, the false prophet will be able to make "fire come down from heaven on the earth in the sight of men" (Revelation 13:13), and the ultimate antichrist will evidently appear to die and come back to life, igniting an explosive movement of the masses in following him (Revelation 13:3-4).  God even warns the Israelites in the Old Testament not to follow a prophet who seduces them to go after other gods, even if his prophecy comes true (Deuteronomy 13:2; see also, II Thessalonians 2:8-10).  In other words, a Christian should check every belief against the word of God.
Second, the Holy Spirit is also an epistemological Source in our hearts, both positively (what to believe) and negatively (what to reject).  For example, 1 John 2:20, 27 talks about how the Holy Spirit can teach us what is true; i.e., by giving us a confirming sense in our hearts that what we are hearing is so (we sometimes call this "conviction"); or, by giving us an uneasy sense that something about what we're hearing is "off," even if we don't know what.  Jesus said the Holy Spirit would teach us what to say, when the time comes, when standing before rulers and judges (Luke 12:11-12).  However, for this to work, a Christian has the responsibility to remain "in the Spirit" day by day, and throughout the day, to be guided by the Holy Spirit in every area of life (which we can often fail at, to varying degrees).  To the extent we allow bitterness, pride, or worldliness into our hearts, for example, then our hearts become hardened against the Holy Spirit's influence; but if we remain close to God, the Holy Spirit can guide us in our hearts, and in the very moment when we need it.  Further, as we pray for guidance, the Holy Spirit can give us peace about which path to take, or uneasiness about one to avoid.  This also helps us to better recognize divinely orchestrated events by more clearly understanding God's will.
Beyond that, a various mix of things can be factored into distinguishing God's working in our lives from mundane events.  For instance, for myself and Christians I know closely and trust, we have seen God give us comfort during trying times through incredible "coincidences" which we know aren't really "coincidences" at all.  It's not the mere improbability, but the conjunction of improbability with significance; and above that, usually "sealed" or signed with a strong inner sense of peace at the same time; something amazing, and right during the narrow window of time when it really counts, and that also has God's "fingerprints" on it (i.e., just like something He'd do).  I certainly do take these as personal messages from God, and as reminders that He is with us, cares for us, and is still in control.  Biblically, God doesn't necessarily promise us these additional "signs," but in many cases, He gives them to us anyway, just because He can and because He loves us, I suppose.  Some stories are more personal and would require a rather elaborate background to fully catch the significance, but many have been published in books (I've listed a couple below).  Now of course, anyone can claim a miracle or "sign," and I've read some where it just doesn't "ring true" to me; but others that I've read, I am inclined to believe, based on my own experience, and that of many whom I know and trust, and when the events are consistent with God's character.  But I don't think God generally gives them for the purpose of evangelism anyway, but as means of personal comfort.
Maybe a couple of final points before the examples—Since, as Christians, we already know God, it is far less "extraordinary" in our view to see something as God's working.  (At least, it ought to be!  :)  And so it's not like we have to "ask for receipts" and all the "proof" that God did it; if it's the best explanation, given God's immense concern and care for us (Matthew 10:29-30), then it makes a lot of sense to see it as being from God.  Finally, getting to know God is sort of like an "unfolding" thing (as with any relationship, I'd say).  The more we get to know Him, the more He "opens up" to us.  I.e., the first signs God gives to us are things like the resurrection of Jesus Christ, or the design of nature (Matthew 16:4; Romans 1:20).  Only after we accept that does God "open up" to us more (e.g., Matthew 13:58).  It's sort of like a "treasure hunt"; we can expect to get more clues only after we follow the instructions we've been given already, so to speak.  Epistemologically speaking, then, much of the knowledge "further down" in the relationship—even how we know—is not easily expressed or debated, given its highly internal and relational nature, coupled with an (often) interdependence on past things we've learned about God's character.
Examples
Brother Andrew
There is a book called God's Smuggler, an autobiography by a man named Brother Andrew, who smuggled Bibles to countries behind the Iron Curtain.  Unfortunately I don't have his book handy, but he tells about how many times, he decided to simply trust God and not even try to hide the Bibles when smuggling them across the borders.  Once, I think, he had a box open, and one of the Bibles casually laying beside the box, as they pulled up in their car to the customs officials at the border.  Sometimes the guards would not even check; once, I think, a guard actually opened a suitcase full of Bibles, but Brother Andrew kept talking nonchalantly about something else with another of the guards.  The guard checking the suitcase simply seemed to be listening in on the conversation, and just closed the suitcase and let them go through.  I'd say that's a pretty amazing miracle!  Whether we consider it as God giving Brother Andrew uncanny shrewdness, or gave him an ability to keep calm, or appealed to the guards' sympathy, or blinded the eyes of the guards to what they were actually seeing, or a combination of these things, I'd say this was a work of God.
Percy Ray
There's a biography I once was able to read about a Christian evangelist called Percy Ray: A Ray for God (I've met an elderly lady who was saved at one of his revival meetings; he used to preach around the area I live).  It has some amazing stories.  The book is hard to come by (I read it from a church library), so I'm going off of memory...but for instance, once Percy Ray was praying hard for some money they needed, I think to run a camp he had started (they were poor, and it was difficult to keep it afloat).  A friend was praying with him, and they needed the money soon.  After a while Percy got up and was all excited and said God had answered their prayers; and when they checked the mail that day, there was a check that covered what they needed.  I'd say that was the working of God, both in giving them the money, and in giving Percy the assurance that it was taken care of.  I wish I could remember more, and if I ever get that book again, I'll try to write some of them down.
Corrie Ten Boom
Here are two excerpts from a book by Corrie Ten Boom, The Hiding Place (c2006, published by Chosen Books, Grand Rapids, MI), which seem especially relevant, since Corrie and Betsie (her sister) effectively discuss epistemology in this way (though briefly).  The story of Corrie Ten Boom is fairly well-known in Christian circles.
This first account below is a sort of vision that Corrie had, which she describes (pp. 79-80):

And it was then that I had the dream.  It couldn't have been a real dream because I was not asleep.  But a scene was suddenly and unreasonably in my mind.  I saw the Grote Markt, half a block away, as clearly as though I were standing there, saw the town hall and St. Bavo's and the fish mart with its stair-stepped facade.
Then as I watched, a kind of odd, old farm wagon—old fashioned and out of place in the middle of a city—came lumbering across the square pulled by four enormous black horses.  To my surprise I saw that I myself was sitting in the wagon.  And Father too!  And Betsie!  There were many others, some strangers, some friends.  I recognized Pickwick and Toos, Willem and young Peter.  All together we were slowly being drawn across the square behind those horses.  We couldn't get off the wagon, that was the terrible thing.  It was taking us away—far away, I felt—but we didn't want to go. . . . [ellipses original]
"Betsie!" I cried, jumping up, pressing my hands to my eyes.  "Betsie, I've had such an awful dream!"
I felt her arm around my shoulder.  "We'll go down to the kitchen where the light won't show, and we'll make a pot of coffee."
The booming of the bombs was less frequent and farther away as Betsie put on the water.  Closer by was the wail of fire alarms and the beep of the hose trucks.  Over coffee, standing at the stove, I told Betsie what I had seen.
"Am I imagining things because I'm frightened? But it wasn't like that! It was real. Oh, Betsie, was it a kind of vision?"
Betsie's finger traced a pattern on the wooden sink worn smooth by generations of ten Booms. "I don't know," she said softly. "But if God has shown us bad times ahead, it's enough for me that He knows about them. That's why He sometimes shows us things, you know—to tell us that this too is in His hands."

Indeed, they were eventually found out by the Gestapo for hiding Jews and carried to a concentration camp, where Betsie and Corrie's father died, among others.  I take it as God's way of mentally preparing and steeling Corrie for the tough times that He knew lay ahead; given the intense impression the vision had on Corrie at the time, the very unusual nature of it, the way it came true, and the fact that it helped Corrie to be more mentally prepared and strong during what lay ahead.
Later, Corrie recounts a miracle with the Davitamon bottle (vitamin) while they were in a concentration camp (p. 213):

Another strange thing was happening.  The Davitamon bottle was continuing to produce drops.  It scarcely seemed possible, so small a bottle, so many doses a day.  Now, in addition to Betsie, a dozen others on our pier were taking it.
My instinct was always to hoard it—Betsie was growing so very weak! But others were ill as well.  It was hard to say no to eyes that burned with fever, hands that shook with chill.  I tried to save it for the very weakest—but even these soon numbered fifteen, twenty, twenty-five. . . . [ellipses original]
And still, every time I tilted the little bottle, a drop appeared at the top of the glass stopper.  It just couldn't be!  I held it up to the light, trying to see how much was left, but the dark brown glass was too thick to see through.
"There was a woman in the Bible," Betsie said, "whose oil jar was never empty." She turned to it in the Book of Kings, the story of the poor widow of Zarephath who gave Elijah a room in her home: "The jar of meal wasted not, neither did the cruse of oil fail, according to the word of Jehovah which he spoke by Elijah."
Well—but—wonderful things happened all through the Bible.  It was one thing to believe that such things were possible thousands of years ago, another to have it happen now, to us, this very day.
And yet it happened, this day, and the next, and the next, until an awed little group of spectators stood around watching the drops fall onto the daily rations of bread.
Many nights I lay awake in the shower of straw dust from the mattress above, trying  to fathom the marvel of supply lavished upon us. "Maybe," I whispered to Betsie, "only a molecule or two really gets through that little pinhole—and then in the air it expands!"
I heard her soft laughter in the dark. "Don't try too hard to explain it, Corrie. Just accept it as a surprise from a Father who loves you."
... [Later, they received some vitamins] ...
... "We'll finish the drops [from the Davitamon bottle] first," I decided.
But that night, no matter how long I held it upside down, or how hard I shook it, not another drop appeared.


The basic assumption is of weakly interactive spiritual dualism.  That there are spiritual entities that seek to communicate with us, and the world is influenceable, but that the limitations of the spiritual entity tend to limit those influences to indirect, subtle, or suggestive rather than explicit or directly helpful interactions.
The assumptions here tend not to mesh very well with the theology of monotheism, where God is assumed to be all powerful, and all knowing, and there would therefore be no reason to limit clarity or effectiveness of communications or interventions. The theologies that better match these assumptions are shamanism, where one is interacting with very limited power spiritual entities, or di-theism, where an enemy God is blocking most of what a good God tries to do, so subtle and stealth interventions are God's work-around.
The epistemology is just that of any inference. If one is asking a question, and then gets what appears to be a useful answer, then it is reasonable to assume there is an answerer, who provided the answer.  If this happens to one repeatedly, then one should look for these sorts of subtle communications as a matter of course.

OP: "how does one distinguish between mundane events and divinely orchestrated ones?"

If—and it seems plausible—the meaningful coincidence or
“cross-connection” of events cannot be explained causally,  then the
connecting principle must lie in the equal significance of parallel
events; in other words, their tertium comparationis is meaning.

from The Interpretation of Nature and the Psyche, page 91.

How does this answer the question? Can you explain in your own words?

The meaningfulness is the distinguishing factor.

Please elaborate? Surely a more detailed answer can be written, right?

As far as answering "could there be grounds to interpret [an event] as a divine message?" the only information available is the meaning carried, which one would have to assess. That's the gist of Jung's statement: that there is no other information or causality. E.g. (from the above link) "The great difficulty is that we have absolutely no scientific means of proving the existence of an objective meaning which is not just a psychic product."

@user80226 To a kid with a mind, everything looks like a thought. It's a sort of Midas touch.
