Is it reasonable to view religions as theories, and, if so, to examine their theoretical predictions in order to test them empirically?
Are religions theories? If they are, what would prevent us from studying the theoretical implications of a religious theory in order to identify testable predictions? Are there any religions that could be viewed as theories of reality offering empirically testable predictions?

Further thoughts
On the other hand, if a religion makes no testable predictions whatsoever about reality—nothing that can be empirically experienced—then our experience of reality would be indistinguishable whether or not the religion is true. There would be no aspect of our experience that could confirm or disconfirm its claims, leaving the religion with nothing meaningful to say about the world we live in. In that case, what purpose would the religion serve? It wouldn't offer anything useful or actionable to enhance our understanding of reality, nor contribute to practical advancements like developing new technologies or curing diseases.

Definition of Religion
I'll quote the definition provided by the Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy's entry on Philosophy of Religion:

Ideally, a guide to the nature and history of philosophy of religion would begin with an analysis or definition of religion. Unfortunately, there is no current consensus on a precise identification of the necessary and sufficient conditions of what counts as a religion. We therefore currently lack a decisive criterion that would enable clear rulings whether some movements should count as religions (e.g., Scientology or Cargo cults of the Pacific islands). But while consensus in precise details is elusive, the following general depiction of what counts as a religion may be helpful:

A religion involves a communal, transmittable body of teachings and prescribed practices about an ultimate, sacred reality or state of being that calls for reverence or awe, a body which guides its practitioners into what it describes as a saving, illuminating or emancipatory relationship to this reality through a personally transformative life of prayer, ritualized meditation, and/or moral practices like repentance and personal regeneration. [This is a slightly modified definition of the one for “Religion” in the Dictionary of Philosophy of Religion, Taliaferro & Marty 2010: 196–197; 2018, 240.]

This definition does not involve some obvious shortcomings such as only counting a tradition as religious if it involves belief in God or gods, as some recognized religions such as Buddhism (in its main forms) does not involve a belief in God or gods. Although controversial, the definition provides some reason for thinking Scientology and the Cargo cults are proto-religious insofar as these movements do not have a robust communal, transmittable body of teachings and meet the other conditions for being a religion. (So, while both examples are not decisively ruled out as religions, it is perhaps understandable that in Germany, Scientology is labeled a “sect”, whereas in France it is classified as “a cult”.) For a discussion of other definitions of religion, see Taliaferro 2009, chapter one, and for a recent, different analysis, see Graham Oppy 2018, chapter three. The topic of defining religion is re-engaged below in the section 4, “Religion and Science”. But rather than devoting more space to definitions at the outset, a pragmatic policy will be adopted: for the purpose of this entry, it will be assumed that those traditions that are widely recognized today as religions are, indeed, religions. It will be assumed, then, that religions include (at least) Hinduism, Buddhism, Daoism, Confucianism, Judaism, Christianity, Islam, and those traditions that are like them. This way of delimiting a domain is sometimes described as employing a definition by examples (an ostensive definition) or making an appeal to a family resemblance between things. It will also be assumed that Greco-Roman views of gods, rituals, the afterlife, the soul, are broadly “religious” or “religiously significant”. Given the pragmatic, open-ended use of the term “religion” the hope is to avoid beginning our inquiry with a procrustean bed.


Voting to close unless any hint is given of why the question makes sense. Else this reads like "Are rocks animals? If not what's the purpose of rocks if we cannot breed and eat them?"

@tkruse It's not like "are rocks animals" because he's right, religions are theories. You're downvoting (presumably) and VTC because you don't agree. Don't do that. Christianity for example makes predictions about what will happen after you die, and if you die and do not observe those predictions, those predictions have been falsified.

I've heard John Lennox say that many of the founders of modern science were Christians, expecting to find law in nature because of their faith in a divine Legislator.  If that's the case, then Christianity kicked the door open to the science that led to our modern innovations!

If christianity is a theory, it is wildly not self-consistent. For example, the variety and mutability of the claims for the post-death experience is vast. If christianity is a science, then so is the annual Fashion Week in New York.

It's better to say that each religion has beliefs and practices that can be treated as theory in the same way that science has beliefs and practices that are treated as theory. For religion these include the afterlife, the nature of God's existence, and the resurrection of Jesus. Each religion has individual beliefs about each.

This seems like a natural question. I'm pretty sure I thought of something like this in high school or college.

@JonathanZ, It is silly to claim "Christianity" is inconsistent because Christians disagree with each other. Science is wildly inconsistent in the same sense you claim Christianity is. In fact, I can't think of any sizable tradition or doctrine or set of theories that isn't inconsistent in the same sense.

No, they are not; and if we consider them as theories their "predictions" (eternal life, etc) are simply unverifiable and useless.

@causative the OP specifically asked about whether religions make theories about this life and reality, not the afterlife. They did not ask for being handed pamphlets like the watchtower from each of the cultist on this site advertising their religion, yet now this is what they got.

Tnx @causative for reifying the rampant VTC/delete/flag misuse that is on the increase of late. Sadly I must say it's worse after you've become mod because (guessing) the other mods have more aggressively pushed back against your more laid back style

OP, one thing to add to your mind is that religion is a word that barely means anything. "Religion" is basically a bucket term for anything that's superficially similar to what Christians do differently when they're doing Christian worship than when they're doing Christian non-worship. This would already generate all kinds of errors in categorization if Christianity was a fairly ordinary example of sect-teaching, but Christianity is an extreme outlier in any sensible taxonomy of sect-teachings.

Tnx the comment @gs. I would only  (perhaps) tone down the "extreme" (though I may have said similar myself ☺️). The more objective fact is that all religions are outliers along some or other axis. What is true us that Christianity's outlierness more directly hits on phil-SE because Christian evangelists, by being Logos-centric,  more militantly make strong and decisive truth claims. See Logos vs Mythos. Centering a religion on truth claims is really weird. Sure religions point to truth but not discourse able truth. Eg Tao te ching 1st.

@gs I quoted a definition of "Religion" from the SEP.

...which either goes 1-step circular with "sacred" or includes political ideologies as religions. I think it's best to just not try to use English, and pick a different language with a more useful word that overlaps the same set of ideas with a different connotation.

@JonathanZ So is every other religion. Hindu: Krishna is supreme? Yes. Shiva is supreme? Yes Buddhist: Is there rebirth. Yes. Also No Islam: Christianity is false because it idolatrizes Jesus. Yet thousand fold more muslim parents name their sons Muhammed than Christian parents do for Jesus etc etc. So Christianity is inconsistent is fine. Christianity alone is inconsistent is nonsense

I need to say @tkruse, that I have as much agreement as  disagreement with you.  (a) I agree that brazen evangelism is not ok — the VTC process is not nearly enough.  It needs to be penalized closer to spam. And (b) Christian evangelists outnumbering others, it seems ok to deal with them more heavy handedly. However your VTC etc usage is disagreeable and out of line with the norms and rules of this place...

... as @causative pointed out

Having said that, the "test" has been dobe already; see Joshua 10:13 "And the sun stood still, and the moon stopped, until the nation took vengeance on their enemies. Is this not written in the Book of Jashar? The sun stopped in the midst of heaven and did not hurry to set for about a whole day." Since Galileo Galilei, this biblical "prediction" has been refuted.

@MauroALLEGRANZA   Joshua 10:13 (and such) is not merely a miracle problem but a more fundamental philosophy problem. When there is a discrepancy between heavenly body tine and clock time, which wins? See. And if time is defined by the movement of heavenly bodies what does it mean that a day passed and the sun didn't set? This is the same issue as the one with Genesis-1: How can even God create the sun, moon on the 1st day?

Perhaps we should just stick to present time and evaluate any given religious claim in isolation and see what we can find out? Ignore the non-testable ones, what is there which can be tried now? Meet the question on it's own terms. That's Philosophy.

@Rushi - Read comment right above mine; it's the one that moves from "religions" to "Christianity". I agree that all religions are, but it's noticeable that the comment that claimed some good for just Christianity went uncriticized, while my critical response got the "but all religions" reply.

@ScottRowe Ppl who exercise have better lives than ppl who waste their time on internet fora — a prosaic testable proposition. Likewise: ppl who have a religious commitment have better lives than those who dont seems as straightforwardly testable. Whether James Bond is truer than Harry Potter seems (to me) irrelevant to which is better for a child's education

@JonathanZ Maybe you missed my comment to tkruse above? Also elsewhere

@Rushi, I don't think hardly anyone in philosophy thinks it is hard to distinguish between time itself and the measurement of time using heavenly bodies. How to keep time is a question for governments and standards bodies, not philosophers.

@Rushi, I wasn't mocking you; I was just making a point. In the Joshua quote, the measurement of time seems like a non-issue. People can judge the passage of time without external queues. People in those days were much more experienced at the practice than people to day because they didn't have clocks. And "about a whole day" is a vague determination of time. Your point on Genesis is wrong for missing the real problem which is that Genesis is defining day by "evening and morning" so how could they have evening and morning without the sun already existing and the earth already rotating?

I cut out some of the SEP citation to try to stave off closure (which is at 4 votes). Feel free to roll back, but long citations, in my experiences, meet a hostility and one more vote will tip the scale to closed.

There are claims about future events that are verifiable, we just don't know when they are going to happen.  But if and when they do...

The question is perfectly clear, and should not have been closed.  We have 12 answers and counting, and 11 upvotes and counting on one of the answers, so the community here is appreciative of both the question and the answers.

@Rushi if it is in fact observed that people with a religious commitment have better lives, then people would likely want to know why? If it turned out that the commitment part caused the effect and not the religious part, then we should throw out the non-functional part and emphasize the part that causes the improvement. Builders of submarines found that dolphins have more efficiency in moving through water than a sub. It wasn't the shape, it was the blubber under the skin. So, subs would work better if they were soft. Sharks have sandpapery skin which helps in another way. We could find out.

@ScottRowe  By curious coincidence, I just saw this viz. In at least 1 in 10 cases Buddhist meditation makes life worse! So much for our wish for maintaining fidelity with empirical data

@Rushi so was it the Buddhist part or the meditation part that was causing the problem? It is widely known that meditation will bring up any psychological problems people have and make them 'worse'. But then, a lot of medical treatments can seem to do the same thing. Maybe 'worse' is a prerequisite to 'better' in a lot of cases? Or, maybe some people just shouldn't meditate. Nobody should be Buddhist, because nobody should be anything.

@ScottRowe Everyone has a potential for spirituality. But everyones style is different. See ishta devata. In the Chinese paradigm, you can see the world as fundamentally bitter, sour or sweet. I think it's just silly to legislate subjective questions like this. [Eg. I dislike chocolate; that puts me in some 10%(?) of the population. Should you decide whether the 10% or the 90% are right?]

"There would be no aspect of our experience that could confirm or disconfirm its claims, leaving the religion with nothing meaningful to say about the world we live in. In that case, what purpose would the religion serve?"
This part of your question seems to be missing the central purpose of religion.  The central purpose of religion is not about this world, but the next.

@Chozag Right (in the case of those religions that make no testable predictions about this life, before death). However, even afterlife predictions would only matter as long as we actually get to experience an afterlife. If we die and nothing happens, then afterlife predictions would be falsified.

A religion can be treated as a theory for some purposes. So can a political movement or artistic movement or folk psychology. Let's call such things, doctrinal traditions. Note, the word "doctrine" doesn't imply religion here; it just means a set of beliefs. Science is also a doctrinal tradition.
Now, doctrinal traditions are only theories in the weak sense that they involve a set of propositions and the people who assert those propositions would probably also assent to any proposition that you could convinces them is a logical consequence of those propositions. But doctrinal traditions are unlike what we usually think of as theories in three important ways: first there isn't a single set of propositions that constitutes a doctrinal tradition. It is almost always the case that different people in the same doctrinal tradition have different beliefs. You might be able to come up with a core set of beliefs held by everyone in the tradition, but you would be surprised how small that core is. Second, doctrinal traditions change and evolve over time. Third, theories are generally assumed to have precise definitions and precise propositions such that everyone can agree whether or not something falls under a given definition and whether or not a given proposition about a given object is true, but doctrinal traditions tend to be messily imprecise and fuzzy. (I'll note that there is a branch  of logic called fuzzy logic that tries to deal with this, but I won't go into that).
In addition, most doctrinal traditions make claims that are about the real world, but are not testable in the same sense that, for example, a theory of macroscopic physics is testable. For example, Christianity claims that there is an afterlife, and although they can present various sorts of evidence for this, they can't prove it in the way that you can prove theories of macroscopic physics. Christianity also makes moral claims that can't be tested. How would you test the claim that murder is wrong? Or abortion? But just because you can't test the truth of those claims doesn't mean that they have nothing meaningful to say. Surely the claim, "You shouldn't try to kill that guy who cut you off in traffic even if you can get away with it." is meaningful. And surely claims about the afterlife are also meaningful, even if they can't be proved.
Pretty much every doctrinal tradition has untestable claims. Republicans claim that the economy would have been better if Trump had remained in office, but if you don't accept their economic theories, you have no way of testing the claim. Democrats claim that Trump is a secret fascist but how can you test the inside of his skull to know that he really believes the opposite of what he says? There are various art traditions that claim that one thing or another is more beautiful, but there is no objective test for beauty. Still although none of these claims is testable, they are all significant and important claims that ought to direct our actions in certain ways if we believe them.
The amazing success of certain scientific fields has led people to believe that everything in life can be treated like those fields, but it can't. There are even fields of science that have untestable assertions; for example, how are you going to test that a rock was shaped as a tool instead of by accident? There is nothing to go on but the human judgment. Real life is messy, imprecise, and uncertain, and there is no magical methodology to make it neat, precise, and certain.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Religion is a worldview which relies on an anthromorphic model. Religion attempts to explain and often to control the world on the basis of personal relations between some deity and the human world.

The big epistemic handicap of a religious worldview is that it
cannot be tested.
Either because it claims are transcendent from the
start, i.e. they refer to a domain beyond the usual experience. Or
because its statements are compatible with any experience, i.e.
the religious worldview is immunized against any refutation.

History shows that religions accompany mankind in all cultures and
through all times.
The omnipresence of religion is not due to its explanatory value as a successful theory. The strenght of
religions is their high flexibility to adept to every existential
situation and to create hope and consolation.


Of course the phenomenon of religion cannot be treated exhaustively in a short answer like this. It needs further investigation from the viewpoint of  psychology of religion and from sociology.

In most ways, no, religions are not theories, because they are not falsifiable.  Historical inaccuracies in religious texts?  No problem, they're allegorical.  World events not indicative of a loving deity?  No problem, they work in mysterious ways.  Some of the teachings seem logically contradictory?  No problem, belief isn't rooted in logic but in faith.
It's pretty easy to test this:  Go find an adherent to some religion X and ask them "What could conceivably happen right now that would cause you to stop believing in your religion?"  If the answer is "Nothing", then their belief is not a theory.

I don't think it's an either / or, though; Christians' faith in Jesus can be relational, transcending science, etc., yet the Bible can still be scientifically testable.  I heard an evangelist ask a man, "If I said I had scientific proof your wife doesn't exist, would you consider giving up your belief that she does?" Well, no, of course not; and while he may have an unshakable faith in her existence, that doesn't preclude it from also being an empirical, scientific fact.

@PeterRankin "Well, no, of course not" - this presumes that we can conjure up strong scientific evidence that his wife doesn't exist, despite the fact that she does exist.  IMHO, if your pastor, friends and family are insisting that they can't see your wife, and are presenting you with stong evidence that, e.g., your wife died years ago, then I think you should seriously consider the possibility that your wife doesn't exist.  I've seen too many people wandering down the sidewalk talking to nobody to feel very confident that such a thing couldn't happen to me.

Except there are plenty of people for whom there does exist evidence that could (and sometimes does) convince them to stop believing in those same religions, which suggests that the thing that the thing that isn't a theory is something personal to the believer - the belief in the religion, rather than the religion itself.

Not downvoting, but scientific theories are generally accepted to require falsifiability. Theory taken more broadly is more like a collection of abstract thoughts or a corpus of works with a conceptual motif: "A theory is a rational type of abstract thinking about a phenomenon, or the results of such thinking. The process of contemplative and rational thinking is often associated with such processes as observational study or research. Theories may be scientific, belong to a non-scientific discipline, or no discipline at all"

@Him as you pointed out in your comment reply, people can just be factually wrong about their self-assessments. The answers to questions are data about the way people answer those questions, not facts about the people. (Except for the 6% of Americans who answer 'yes' to whether they could beat up a grizzly bear bare-handed. Those ones are just factually correct. Awesome.)

Scientific theories are also not falsifiable, per Quine-Duhem.  False dichotomy. The difference between science and dogma is attitudinal.  Science involves the effort to seek out disconfirming test cases, and accept that one needs to adapt a theory to account for them, while dogmatism involves only seeking out confirming test cases, and then using them to convince oneself of the "truth" of the theory.  Religion can be held with a scientific mindset.

All worldviews are "theories", or at least a diffuse family of theories, sort of like Lakatos's Research Programs, but more diffuse.  The "diffuseness" is due to religions not actually being constructed carefully and clearly like formal theories are, and the multiple sources of reference claims, and varying interpretations of any claim, that characterize an organically developed worldview, as opposed to a formal theory.
Religious worldviews are testable.  However, due to the diffusivity and varying interpretations, tests are suggestive, not definitive.
There are well known tests.  The Problem of Evil, and the Hiddenness of God, are well known test cases that provide strongly negative suggestions as to the validity of many religions.
A more specific test was done on Shinto, when the Holy Islands, home of the Gods, was the only location on earth Nuked in anger.  The subsequent drop in adherence to Shinto in Japan is attributable to this being seen by many as a failed test case.
As I noted above, the Quine-Duhem thesis applies to the envelope of a religion's views, and under Quine-Duhem, one can always find SOME rationale why a test might not be refuting, by complexifying the theory.  The added theoretic complexity in many cases  vitiates of testability that religion.  That apologists resort to this is why you seem to think religions are meaningless.  It is not necessarily the only plausible response.  Another possible response to test cases would be to change major doctrines that served to lead to test failures.

I guess you are referring to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Itsukushima but there is no mention of nuking it. It is next to Hiroshima but structures on island have not been affected.

@Piro The Gods live throughout Japan, and consider it particularly holy. They destroyed the only prior invasion of the islands, with the Kami Kazi.  Their failure to protect the holy islands was a failure of their powers.  https://japancientnz.weebly.com/shinto-gods.html

The answer, properly speaking, should be no. Religions are not theories. Within religions, there exist many theories, but a religion is a school of thought. I am a Christian, and what I share with other Christians is not a set of testable hypotheses, it's a set of doctrines. In other words, it's a set of assumptions about reality: Jesus is God incarnate, he died on the cross and rose again, the Bible is generally reliable, there will be a last judgment, etc. We also share a set of ethical principles, derived from the Bible and Christian tradition. Now, you are perfectly within your rights to look at those assumptions and assess whether they comport with your observation of the world, but not a single one amounts to a testable hypothesis. The closest thing to that is claims about historical fact. While those do encroach on the here-and-now, it is facially absurd to think that some experiment we can do now would test whether some event happened then.
In this way, Christianity is a mode of thinking, complete with its own assumptions and way of looking at the world. This is, in a way, much like science, which has its own set of assumptions. Unlike science, however, Christianity does not emphasize the testable; our emphases are relational and ethical. In this way, the two modes of thought (science and Christianity) almost always end up answering different questions. I wouldn't go quite as far as Gould's "non-overlapping magisteria" view that science and religion can never possibly intersect. But practically speaking, they rarely if ever collide.
Nevertheless, within the umbrella of Christianity, there exist many testable theories: If I pray in a certain way, will I witness a miracle? If we structure our church in certain way, will we get better attendance? If I practice a certain discipline, will I improve my life in measurable ways? These are practical questions which can in theory be tested, and many of them actually are tested by Christians who want to know the best way to practice our religion (c.f. Romans 12:2). However, none of them is a test of whether Christianity is true or not.
While I am not as familiar with other religions, I assume that the situation is similar.

@ScottRowe It's a false dichotomy that either something is testable or it's just personal preference. For example, in political questions, we aren't just asking "will this policy achieve its desired end?" (an empirical question) but more commonly, "what end is desirable?" (a moral, untestable question), but that doesn't mean that it's "just personal preference" what goal our policies aim at. Since many goals are mutually exclusive, we as a society must impose something on those who disagree. It is not possible not to.

@DarkMalthorp "If I pray in a certain way, will I witness a miracle?" - Is this really a testable prediction made by Christianity? If so, how precisely is the "certain way" defined theoretically?

@DarkMalthorp "If I practice a certain discipline, will I improve my life in measurable ways?" - Are there more concrete and specific (less vague) versions of this testable prediction?

@user80226 sure - "if I have daily prayer and accountability check-ins, will I be able to break an addiction to alcohol?"

Regarding the prayer -> miracles, that is not a testable prediction made by Christianity generally, as I said in my answer. Rather, it is testable prediction made by some Christians, especially in the Pentacostal/Charismatic movements.

@DarkMalthorp "if I have daily prayer and accountability check-ins, will I be able to break an addiction to alcohol?" - How is this not reducible to psychology (e.g., how is this not just a particular kind of therapeutic treatment)? Or this prediction implicitly assuming some kind of supernatural/divine assistance in the process enabled by the prayer? Hence the request for less vagueness / more specificity in the details of the prediction. A theory of how this is supposed to work ideally should specify all those minor details.

@DarkMalthorp "Rather, it is testable prediction made by some Christians, especially in the Pentecostal/Charismatic movements." - Do you have a source where this prediction is fleshed out in much more detail?

@user80226 - No it's just something I've encountered before. Regarding psychology, yes there's a lot of overlap. To separate everything into "natural" vs. "supernatural" in cleanly cut categories isn't really the way Christians think about things. We beleive that God works through the natural order, so it's not an either-or question.

@DarkMalthorp "We believe that God works through the natural order" - But then how do you distinguish between God working through the natural order vs. the natural order just doing its own thing without God working through it? For example, if the wind is moving the curtains in my apartment, how do you epistemologically determine that God has a specific plan in mind with the angles in which the curtains are moving vs. this is just the wind moving my curtains without any deeper meaning to it? I already asked this question by the way, see https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/117745/80226

@user80226 The natural order doesn't just "do it's own thing", God works in everything (Col.1:16-17, Prov.16:11,Rev.4:11, Matt.10:29 etc. etc.) This obviously doesn't mean everything is equally meaningful, just like not everything that you do is equally important. How do we distinguish importance is a complicated topic that I don't have time to explain fully, and there is a range of opinions within Christendom, but I suggest you ask your Christian acquaintances about it.

@DarkMalthorp I'd be happy if you just share a link to a source that explains it.

@DarkMalthorp Unfortunately, I've learned what I know from many sources and can't point you to just one. One important concept is laid out well in Prince Caspian chapter 11 with the conversation between Lucy and Aslan where Aslan doesn't say anything, because Lucy already knows the answers. Most of the time when I see God working in the mundane events, he's just reminding me of things I already know.

This sounds reminiscent of a Socratic conversation, where Socrates' questions are simple and serve to being out what the other person knows implicitly, and then it is explicit. I know of a psychological phenomenon like that.

@DarkMalthorp Based on your answer here, I think you would probably answer this question with a 'yes'.

@user80226 Sure. I think that's a reasonable analogy. One (very) big difference is that a religion is not primarily a quest for true knowledge, though it does usually include that. The underlying goal of science and religion is different. And even worse than that (if you're trying to define precisely "religion"), the underlying goal of different religions is also not the same.

@DarkMalthorp Check out this question.

A system of statements has to be consistent to qualify as a theory so religions are not theories. Religions are usually a mix of statements, beliefs that the statements are true, and rites.
Given that different religions make very different statements, it is not self-evident that the content of religious statements really matters. If they did, surely people would demand proof that these statements are true. It seems that the rites are really what holds a religion together.
I don't know of any religion presented outright as fiction. All religions make claims about reality, but they are invariably unfalsifiable, and you have to wonder why.
There is no system of religious statements which is sufficiently explicit and detailed for there to be anything to falsify. It would be for religious people themselves to seek to falsify what they believe, but this is clearly not what they want to do, rather the opposite.

Outside of science, a "theory" is roughly synonymous with a guess. One could trivially grant any religion that, and you wouldn't really be any closer to knowing whether that religion is true or involves justified beliefs.
Religion as a scientific theory?
In science, a "theory" refers to "an explanation of an aspect of the natural world and universe that can be (or a fortiori, that has been) repeatedly tested and corroborated in accordance with the scientific method, using accepted protocols of observation, measurement, and evaluation of results".
It's the highest rank an explanation can obtain in science, and it could colloquially be considered a "fact" (there is some distinction between fact and scientific theory, but that's beyond the scope of this answer).
I'm not aware of any part of any religion that's gotten anywhere close to that (except perhaps religions that co-opted existing facts or theories into their religion, religions that provided some vague explanation for something we later found to be roughly correct, via the standard scientific process of hypothesis testing, which is just science, or people bending and stretching what their religious texts say to argue that actually it explains things as science understands them).
Religion as hypotheses
At most, one might consider religious truth claims to be hypotheses: some proposed explanation that hasn't been tested yet. We could then go on to test it. One could test whether following some religious practice reliably leads to a result that a religion claims that it does. One could test various parts of the natural world to determine whether some religious story is likely true or not. Etc.
And every time we try to test it, religion seems to be on the losing end, either by failing to verify the claims (which is often the strongest refutation that science/empiricism can offer for certain types of claims), or the religious claims are outright contradicted by existing facts or theories. But this is a very general claim (it is a question about religions in general).
In other cases, religious truth claims are untestable. Religious views are often criticised for being untestable and lacking any other reliable means of evaluating claims that supports the religion. At that point, it's less a question of science (because science can't test the untestable) and more a question of epistemology - one might say we shouldn't accept such claims.
And if someone says "but every worldview has such claims", firstly, they'd be admitting that they have no good reason for accepting those claims (if asked for a good reason, and you have a good reason, then just give the good reason, rather than responding with whataboutism). And secondly, some would respond that religion adds more such claims than what's necessary or reasonable. Others may respond with simply a "no", directly disagreeing with the idea that such claims are a necessary part of every worldview. But this gets into a broader discussion of epistemology.
Sometimes religious truth claims seem to have absolutely no bearing on our lives one way or the other, like the claim of a creator that doesn't interact with the universe or with humanity (origin-based arguments don't seem sound, but even if they were, and one could conclude a creator from those, you'd still have all your work ahead to get to the truth of any religion worth caring about). Other times, the claims may have some bearing on our lives if true, e.g. claims of an afterlife, but these claims seem unjustified all the same.
Moral claims in religion?
Religion also tends to make moral claims.
Many will say that's objective morality, which would make it a truth claim. But that sounds incoherent, as a moral subjectivist. It's like saying "this action is desirable because", and just stopping right there in the middle of the sentence. It's missing a reason for why we "should" do it, for why we want to do it. See also: the is-ought problem.
What makes more sense to me, is to say we should do it because e.g. it makes God happy, it decreases the suffering of others, or it's self-serving in that it maximises your own personal benefit by giving you eternal life. At that point, we could make it about truth claims. "Make God happy" depends on the truth claims of "God exists" as well as claims about what God likes. Doing something for eternal life depends on the claim of eternal life and the claims for what would get you there. Doing something to decrease suffering in this life depends on claims of what suffering people experience as a result of what, and how one's actions factor into that. We could evaluate all of these truth claims (whether that comes in the form of testing, or looking for other potential justifications).

You ask:

Is it reasonable to view religions as theories, and, if so, to examine their theoretical predictions in order to test them empirically?

Not really. A theory is an abstraction characterizing a coherent collection of information and knowledge, whereas religion is form of social organization usually involving discourse of the divine and having rites and rituals. Religions have theories, but they are not theories in and of themselves.
From the Concept of Religion (SEP):

The most significant shift in the history of the concept is when people began to use religion as a genus of which Christian and non-Christian groups were species... Herbert identified five “articles” or “elements” that he proposed were found in every religion, which he called the Common Notions, namely: the beliefs that

there is a supreme deity,2
this deity should be worshipped,
the most important part of religious practice is the cultivation of virtue,
one should seek repentance for wrong-doing, and
one is rewarded or punished in this life and the next.


Religious "theories" are often called religious doctrine. For a quick introduction, I'd suggest Philosophy of Religion: A Very Short Introduction (GB). It's a good primer on the philosophy of religion. (And is one of my few books on the matter making me no expert on religion.) I don't own them, but two others look applicable: Religion: A Very Short Introduction (GB) and Philosophy and Religion: A Very Short Introduction (GB).


"In that case, what purpose would the religion serve?"

The purpose of our reality is a key question. The science is certainly not ready to tackle global questions pertaining to our existence.
But for the public outside of the scientific world, key questions about our reality have to be answered. And this created room for religious scholars.

I feel this answer has it backwards, since many questions about reality that used to be answered by religions and priests are usually answered scientifically nowadays. Like why there is thunder.

This is unfortunately  the typical modern scientismist-presentist misreading of ancient texts @PhilipKlöcking. When ppl say (for example) how could God create the sun on the first day if the sun defines our very notion of day, they forget that this is such an obvious consideration that it seems absurd to think that authors who could create something as sophisticated as the bible couldn't think of this anomaly, as obvious as saying God made a square circle. Believing that ancients ascribed thunder to a literal thunder god seems as absurd (to me at least).

Why inappropriate behavior leads to pregnancy - was also answered by science. But I am talking about global, philosophical questions, if you will.

@PhilipKlöcking Mechanistic and teleological "why" have almost nothing to do with each other. In the ancient days of superstition, priests answered "why did the chicken cross the road" by claiming that it wanted to get to the other side. Now thanks to science we know better: why did the chicken cross the road? Because it put one foot in front of the other.

@ScottRowe See GS comment above. It answers better than I could many of these issues you raised there

@gs I used your comment above here. Pls expand (if you like)


Are religions theories? If they are, what would prevent us from studying the theoretical implications of a religious theory in order to identify testable predictions?

No, religions are not theories in the scientific sense (the only sense I know, there are maybe others).
A theory states claims that can then be tested and there is a way to falsify the claims. If experiments agree with the theory we say that the theory is good enough. If experiments do not agree then the theory is either invalidated (nothing matches) or its useability is reduced to specific contexts (Newtonian mechanics vs relativity for instance)
A religion states facts that are not for everyone to discuss (depending on the religion, some people may discuss and/or change the claims).
At no point is there an empirical component - and if there is an attempt to have one (gathering evidence for miracles for instance), it does not follow the scientific methodology and certainly does not get to the same conclusions (for instance there is someone who suddenly heals from cancer after having prayed. There are no medical reasons for that. Science will say "there is something new we do not know about", religion will say "miracle")
Now, there may be other approaches than the scientific one, you may have interesting answers about that.


Are there any religions that could be viewed as theories of reality offering empirically testable predictions?

All religions and cults and many pseudosciences prescribe practices to follow to achieve some success in this life, or avoid some calamity.

Christianity suggests prayer for every thinkable kind of benefits
Avoiding food like pork or beef is predicted with all kinds of benefits
Scientology and Psi research suggest training the mind, such as to open a bottle of champagne by staring at it (it really works sometimes!)
Homeopathy predicts potentiation via dilution, but all trials to get very drunk on very diluted alcohol failed

But actually none of that has proven any effectiveness beyond what a placebo practice would equally achieve, and thus such predictions have no proving power. So it's commonly accepted that physical reality is best understood by materialism, and religions are typically limited to the spiritual realm (if there were such a thing) that eludes objective analysis.
Even when scriptures like Genesis make very clear predictions about what archeology should find about the creation of earth, dictated by the creator themselves, when archeology actually finds different things, this does not immediately refute the religion in the eyes of believers. After all faith was never based on such predictions being true, but on conviction gained with life experience.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Okay - Your question is rather confusing but after a thorough readthrough this is what I understand. You asked main 3 questions: These will be referenced by their number

Are religions theories?
Assuming religions are theories, what would prevent us from studying the theoretical implications of a religious theory in order to identify testable predictions?
Are there any religions that could be viewed as theories of reality offering empirically testable predictions?

You also gave a short summary of your train of thought which was basically "If a religion doesn't distinguish/state/conclude/predict something about reality then it is useless and serves no practical purpose."

I want to clarify some definitions before continuing the discussion because things often get confusing if we can't agree on what we're referring to. Definitions are taken from Websters Dictionary unless added in italics by me. (see sources)
(2a) Religion: The service and worship of God or the supernatural. Referenced as a "law" of sorts, a institutionalized system of attitudes, beliefs, and practices about the nature of the universe and God.
Lifestyle / Way of Life: the typical habits, customs, and beliefs of a particular person or group of people or culture.
Beneficial / Value(able): Being of benefit to human development (technology / "theory of relativity" like ideas, etc), health (mentally, physically, or emotionally), or survival.

I disagree with your claim. You say if a religion doesn't distinguish/state/conclude/predict something, let me add a word, TRUE about reality it contributes no value to society, however, adherents to a particular religion might be lead to live a beneficial lifestyle based off a false idea. Consider 2 possible realities in which we could live: The first in which all religions are false because god does not exist and the universe has just always existed as stated by the big bang theory. In this first reality these false religions promote, as we can observe, beneficial lifestyles. In the second reality God is real and religions share particular truths about God, but it is unknown which religion, if possible, truthfully describes the nature of God and the universe. In the second reality religion is still, as we can observe, beneficial to humanity. Therefore, even though a religion doesn't distinguish/state/conclude/predict something TRUE about reality it is still useful and purposeful (of benefit and value)
Now, before answering your 3 main questions there is something you should consider. Religions are often composed of numerous statements, beliefs and truths so even when a certain aspect of a religion is proven false other doctrine might be true. Also the mind of man can misperceive truths stated, so for example, Muhammad (to my understanding) believed that the bible and old testament had been corrupted and misperceived so he wrote his own holy book, the Quran, instead. Anyways, on to the questions:

Sure. Religions (categorically speaking) can be considered theories but as any theory it is unknown where it is true or false. You can demonstrate a theory with a high probability of being true but you can never know for certain. If you know something for certain it is a truth or fact. Christianity is a theory because it is not known to be a absolute truth (stated in their Holy Bible "It is by faith" see Hebrews 11) but, to some, can be demonstrated as having a high probability of being true.

Nothing. Assuming religions are theories (which they are), nothing would prevent us from studying the implications of that theory in order to identify testable predictions.

All religions can be viewed as theories of reality which offer empirically testable predictions. I suggest testing some religions, it is rather fun! I highly suggest exploring the different religions (specifically Christianity being the most profoundly impactful and most heavily debated) because there are 2 possibilities: God is real or God is not. I believe you owe it to yourself to figure out whether he is.



Anyways I hope my answer was helpful, ask any follow up questions you'd like. I'd be happy to help. EDIT( Op added the definition of religion. My answer was written before that definition was stated so diction might be confusing if applied using his provided definition.)
SOURCES
https://www.merriam-webster.com/

"I suggest testing some religions, it is rather fun! I highly suggest exploring the different religions (specifically Christianity being the most profoundly impactful and most heavily debated)" - Are you saying Christianity makes empirically testable predictions?

@user80226 - In response to your first comment:
That is not what I intended with that statement. I was simply recommending that you look further into Christianity in search of what you would define as empirically testable predictions because it has had a significant impact on the modern world both philosophically, sparking numerous debates by the world's greatest minds, and practically, inspiring multitudes of practices, inventions, ideals which profoundly influence the modern world. (For example: peanut oil, the Gregorian calendar, modern science, and the United States of America).

Welcome! If you haven't, please review https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help

Scientific proof negates faith, so the answer to the question is ultimately 'No'.
However, where religions make testable scientific, historical and other testable claims, it is entirely reasonable to weigh those claims against external evidences.

It's very important to specify which standards will be used to weigh those claims. The "can't prove it's wrong" of apologetics is too often used.

Many people have been convinced of the truth of Christianity by the agreement between archeology, for example, and Biblical history.

Really? All the stories I've heard are people staying in Christianity (or maybe returning to) because of a historical find that can't be shown to not correspond to something in the Bible. Do Buddhists ever say "ooh, look at this old pot - I guess affirming Jesus was the son of God will actually affect what happens to me after I die"?

So as for Christianity specifically, not only can many of its claims be analyzed scientifically/historically/etc., but the Bible actually invites that, and on several fronts.  As others have pointed out, though, the most important claims cannot be tested in this way at all.  We cannot possibly prove, with science, that Jesus' death, burial, and resurrection is able to save our souls; nor that New Jerusalem is constructed in the way specified in Revelation 22.  The most important claims are received on faith in God's word, grounded in a trust in His character.  (As an aside, that's not the same as "belief without evidence," though it is belief without direct external evidence for the specific claims; but it's actually quite similar to the way you'd trust certain people you know well about matters you cannot personally verify.)
And so that doesn't mean we can't analyze Christianity in scientific, historic, and logical ways.  If you're listening to a witness in a trial, usually, you would pay attention to the little details in his story, to see if he's telling the truth.  He claims he stopped by the dollar store and bought a Gatorade just minutes before observing the bank robbery; does the credit card company confirm this purchase?  If he seems credible in these details, which of themselves are inconsequential, you are more likely to believe him in the important areas where you cannot verify his story, such as the identity of the person he observed running from the bank and holding a bag full of money.  Similarly, the main point of the Bible isn't simply to be a science or history textbook; and yet God gave us a lot of details in those areas, which helps lend to authenticity.  Things like the exponential decay of human lifespans after the flood when graphed out, the distribution of names given, the way the Bible records even the failures of its heroes, all sorts of little things crossing various studies--can help to demonstrate authenticity.
Here are three examples I can think of in the Bible where God actually invited investigation:

The resurrection of Jesus Christ.  In Matthew 16:4, Jesus said, "A wicked and adulterous generation seeketh after a sign; and there shall no sign be given unto it, but the sign of the prophet Jonas."  I.e., the resurrection of Jesus Christ is specifically provided for investigation.  That's actually how Lee Strobel became a Christian, by investigating it in an attempt to disprove it (because his wife was a Christian).  In the end, he couldn't disprove it, but found the historical case to be very strong, and believed in Jesus himself!  Strobel discusses his investigation in his book The Case for Christ: A Journalist's Personal Investigation of the Evidence for Jesus.  I've also heard about J. Warner Wallace's book, Cold-Case Christianity: A Homicide Detective Investigates the Claims of the Gospels, where he examines the gospels the way he would investigate cold cases professionally, for things such as unintended eyewitness support between the gospels, etc.  I believe he also started out a skeptic, but personally came to believe the gospel accounts due to the evidence he found, i.e., if he was to be true to his real-world manner of investigation for any other "cold case."
Prophecy.  In Isaiah 41:21-24, God challenges the false gods to reveal, and to alter, the future: "Shew the things that are to come hereafter, that we may know that ye are gods: yea, do good, or do evil, that we may be dismayed, and behold it together."  Similarly, another great investigation is into how Jesus Christ fulfilled the prophecy of the Old Testament, such as Isaiah 53 and Psalm 22.  These texts were being faithfully copied by Jewish scribes centuries before Jesus Christ was born.  Josh McDowell discusses this at some length in his book The New Evidence that Demands a Verdict (1999), chapter 8, p. 164-202.  He addresses common counters, such as the date of the Old Testament prophecies, the objection of "coincidence," or the objection that Christians are "reading into" the prophecies.
The global flood.  In II Peter 3:5, the Bible mentions the flood as an evident verification of the Bible's history, and as an analogy of coming judgment: "For this they willingly are ignorant of, that by the word of God the heavens were of old, and the earth standing out of the water and in the water: whereby the world that then was, being overflowed with water, perished: but the heavens and the earth, which are now, by the same word are kept in store, reserved unto fire against the day of judgment and perdition of ungodly men."  And so studying the geologic strata, etc., is a great way to investigate the Bible's history, and more specifically, an evidence, by analogy, of a coming future global judgment.  I was listening to a fluvial geomorphologist, Ron Neller, who used to be an agnostic I think.  But he came to the conclusion even as a non-Christian (later, he did become a Christian) that there was a recent global flood because of a lot of evidences he saw, such as the widespread existence of plateaus, minimal biologic disturbance in the layers, underfit rivers, water gaps, and others.  There's an interview with him in two parts, here, including his journey, and here, along with some of his thoughts on ways people try to explain these things otherwise.  I've seen pictures of fossilized trees sticking up through lots of layers of strata (searching "polystrate tree fossils" yields a lot of photos), photos of bent rock layers (implying reshaping before fully hardening), fossils obviously buried very violently, photos of fish buried in the process of eating other fish, etc.  It's really quite a fascinating topic, and one I believe the Bible singles out for investigation.

There are other examples, too; but the point is that with Christianity anyway, the Bible invites this kind of testing and investigation!

This answer makes several factual claims. Can you please provide citations to back them up?

@user80226 Good idea, I've included some references to books, a video interview with Ron Neller, and links to some online photos of relevant fossils with some analysis.

"... it's actually quite similar to the way you'd trust certain people you know well about matters you cannot personally verify." So, trusting your imaginary friend is different from trusting something without evidence?

As Carl Sagan pointed out in the original Cosmos, religion was at one time a legitimate scientific theory. The problem is, it fell apart upon scientific examination. For example, the power of prayer has been examined extensively and has always failed.
But the adherents didn't see it as a theory, they saw it as a religion, so they ignored the facts and continued to believe these primitive models. Hilarity ensues as Humanity endures religious war after religious war.

When was the last religion war? Of the big wars dominating the news right now, one is over land, the other over influence.

But the participants all see themselves as being in a religious war. God told the Arabs to kill the Jews. Literally.  Jews say, this land is mine because God gave it to me. The MAGA people are doing a religious war too, even though they never put religion in policy statements. === Religion started off as science, thousands of years ago. It was an attempt to explain what's happening. Then evil and ego got stuck onto it, and here we are.

Some things are, for better or worse, out of bounds for basic discussion. So I must be excused!

Everything is in bounds for discussion and you don't need to be excused. Sit your ass back down.

It is notable that the greatest wars in recent memory had nothing to do with religion. The Nazis and Communists were not only non-religious but anti-religious and perceived themselves as scientifically advanced, modern, and enlightened.

The Middle East is. The Arabs say that God told them to kill the Jews,  and the Jews say the land is theirs because God gave it to them. That's religious war enough fo' my ass.

@DarkMalthorp I would call both Naziism and the Japanese warmongering to be religiously motivated. Both movements were fanatical at least, and certainly not reality-based. The current positions of Russia and North Korea are likewise.

@ScottRowe sure, for a sufficiently broad definition of "religious", and likewise for Mao and Stalin, but they've all got little-to-no connection to the historical religions of the world, and none of them were theist. The point is the self perception of being nonreligious, scientifically minded, is no safeguard against horrifying evil. On the flip side, one can point to instances where religion actually pacified formerly warlike cultures, such as the Christianization of the Vikings or Buddhismification of the Mongols.

Basically, I don't see any merit to the notion that there's some correlation between religiousity and violence, either in individuals or in society. One would have to specify certain religious tenets to find such a correlation, but at that point you're not arguing against religion or theism in general, but rather some specific beliefs. And, lurking in the background, is the assumption that war is bad, which (like any other moral proposition) requires some ethical framework that cannot be derived from science.

I've always held out the hope of a negative correlation between religiousity and violence.
