How can theoretical disagreements between competing religious worldviews or "theories" be settled?
In science, two competing theories are evaluated based on several criteria, including falsifiability (the capacity to be proven false), predictive power (the ability to accurately predict phenomena), internal consistency (freedom from contradictions), parsimony (the simplicity or elegance of the explanation), and empirical support (evidence gathered from observations and experiments).
When it comes to evaluating competing religions, however, it’s not immediately clear which, if any, epistemological tools might help determine their relative plausibility. For starters, it's widely accepted that religions are not scientific theories, so comparing them by scientific standards doesn't seem appropriate. Even if we drop the "scientific" qualifier, whether religions can be regarded as "theories" at all is controversial (see Is it reasonable to view religions as theories, and, if so, to examine their theoretical predictions in order to test them empirically?).
Since scientific standards seem to be out of place in this context, what alternative epistemological tools, if any, might help us settle theoretical disagreements between competing religious claims, worldviews, or "theories"?

NOTE: You can think of this question as the philosophy of religion version of How to select between two competing theories?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Voting to reopen because this seems to me like an extremely reasonable question for philosophy.  I don't think the fact it has metaphilosophical implications should be enough to close it, and I also find the essential question to be a very common one.

From another Question: the basis for evaluation depends on your goals. Choosing goals, like choosing your parents, is crucial.


How are theoretical disagreements between competing religious worldviews or "theories" settled?

The OP suggests that there are clear criteria in science to "settle" competing theories, but since religious views are not science those do not seem to be applicable, according to the OP, to religion.
The question, as formulated by the OP, has several very dubious presuppositions which I do not want to (and can not) really address here but which I still want to point out:

Are the listed criteria to "settle" scientific disagreement really that clear? Is each of them necessary? Are all of them together sufficient? Is this actually the way science "works" or is it a simplistic listing that makes scientific practice appear much more "rational" than it actually is? Kuhn's research in historical scientific paradigm change The Structure of Scientific Revolutions could cast some serious doubts on this.
Are those criteria, or more generally "rationality", "common sense", "historical knowledge", not used in religious or theological debate? Is theological debate and argument inherently different from philosophical one (for instance substantive moral debate about what is in concrete situations morally good or what is just or unjust)?
More fundamentally, can we always clearly separate "fact" and "value"? Of course, we can in trivial, unimportant everyday situations. But once core values are concerned, for instance the value of being "humane", or "human rights", we run into difficulties. Imagine you were living in the pre-Civil War period in the US, would you be able to have a rational debate with someone who seriously claimed that blacks are not fully or 'truly' human?

The question, as stated, is very vague. What is "settled" supposed to mean and imply? Empirically - historically - we can see that people do change their adherence to particular religions or world views, that they may in fact feel cognitive dissonance between certain religious doctrines or may feel challenged by other religions. And they use various ways to process that, including various "reasons" -- but which result would then count as being "settled"? Suppose someone with a Christian background first becomes a Buddhist -- so then it's settled for that person? But later they realize that actually the earlier Christian faith could also be interpreted as compatible with Buddhism -- now it's resettled?
The word "settle" suggests the scenario of "settling a dispute". "Settle" then presumably means to convince the other party of one's own truth.
We might hope that two or more "reasonable" parties who have access to all the available "evidence", all the "facts of the matter" (if there are any "facts of the matter"), and who even sincerely agree on those basic facts, would come to the same conclusion - the same judgements about what is so and what is to be done.
We might also hope that if we share common criteria, common standards, written down and accepted as such, in the form of "theories", "general rules", "laws", the reached "settlements" would always be unanimous and therefore acceptable as truth, at least if all parties agree to only accept any reasonings as valid that are compatible with those shared, public standards. But it ain't necessarily so.
The best examples of not being able to reach unanimous settlements, under very strict, agreed-upon conditions of valid reasoning and valid protocol, are law suits -- for instance, cases argued before the the US Supreme Court. There we have a small group of presumably rational and reasonable judges, all agreeing on the presented facts of a case, by law and custom obliged to argue strictly based on the presented facts, on precedents and laws, and still often not able to reach unanimous verdicts. The lack of unanimity can be due to interpretation/perception of particular events (e.g. did a particular action of one of the involved parties express "hostility" or not) or to interpretation/application of particular core values (as expressed in the US Constition for instance) to actual, new circumstances.
(For sample cases, see the dissent of justice Breyer in Carson v. Makin (2022) or the dissent of justices Ginsburg and Sotomayor in Masterpiece Cakeshop v. Colorado Civil Rights Commission (2018).)
The above is the situation when we have something like a common standard to try to "settle" disputes, but what if the standard itself is disputed? Both in religious/theological disputes (in sofar as those are meaningful) and in philosophical ones this may be the case. In the history of science we can also see that, sometimes, certain anomalies necessitate a paradigm shift - which is tantamount to adopting a new standard.
Sextus Empiricus wrote in Against the Logicians

Those who claim for themselves to judge the truth are bound to possess a criterion of truth. This criterion, then, either is without a judge's approval or has been approved. But if it is without approval, whence comes it that it is trustworthy? For no matter of dispute is to be trusted without judging. And, if it has been approved, that which approves it, in turn, either has been approved or has not been approved, and so on ad infinitum.

This suggests that, even in the case where we do possess something like shared standards, there is no ultimate justification for any - in any kind of human endeavor.

Heh! An actual philosophical answer! Nobody seems to recollect that theory from theoria is originally a religion word. IOW theory is a loan word from religion to secular studies

I like this answer, except for the fact that it leaves one without hope of expecting any kind of epistemic progress toward ultimate truths. Since nothing can be ultimately justified, then we are left with relativism, subjectivism, pluralism, and the co-existence of a buffet of mutually contradictory worldviews. Which one is true? We don't know, Whichever you prefer for yourself, etc.

@user80226 - I'm not sure. I think the notion of progress may be misleading. Also, this doesn't necessarily imply that everything is equally valuable - for instance, personally I agree with the dissenting interpretations in the court cases I linked to...

Also, I'm not defending relativism as a kind of doctrine (and neither was Sextus Empiricus).

@mudskipper Then how do you propose that we should go about gaining accurate knowledge about the world? How should we judge and compare the accuracy/plausibility of two competing worldviews (religious or otherwise)?

@user80226 Engineering: use what works best for the particular problem you are trying to solve. Avoid dissent by doing it by yourself.

@user80226 - I agree with Scott Rowe's approach. In practice being practical and pragmatic is enough to keep going. In science (and politics and law) there are accepted protocols to try to keep the outliers in check. The essence of science is not knowledge but research. Knowledge is constantly being challenged and changing.

@mudskipper But how would you apply pragmatism to competing religions? Can pragmatism ever favor one particular religious worldview over another? Perhaps it is more pragmatic to remain agnostic? Is living life under the assumption that there is no God even more pragmatic? Methodological naturalism operates in that way.

@user80226 I often ask myself if my views are helping me. Where they become unquestioned assumptions, or even assumptions I hold unconsciously, then I can make mistakes. Worldviews are just larger assumptions. I make lots of mistakes, so I don't put much faith in my understanding. It leaves me with little way to have faith in anyone or anything else. It's all just judgment calls and bets I am willing to be wrong making. The only certainty I have, I cannot put in words.


How are theoretical disagreements between competing religious worldviews or "theories" settled?

Wikipedia has articles for the labels comparative religion, comparative mythology and comparative theology. None of them seek to settle differences, only to find them (and possibly commonalities). Still those can be a starting point.

Comparative religion is the branch of the study of religions with the systematic comparison of the doctrines and practices, themes and impacts (including migration) of the world's religions.


Comparative mythology is the comparison of myths from different cultures in an attempt to identify shared themes and characteristics.


Comparative theology is a relatively new discipline within theology, which holds together "comparative" and "theology" in creative tension.

As organisations, religions are power hungry self-service entities with zero desire to concede theological defeat to another religion. So the Christian history as an example shows how internal disputes are either suppressed by censure, torture and killing, or lead to a split off of a new religion.
The long term way of settling disputes is for one religion to survive where the other becomes forgotten. This can happen naturally, or forcedly. The Christian tradition of course is a history of forced conversions, such as Inquisition , religious wars, persecution of minority cults, the "stolen generation" of Australia and similar events in US boarding schools for indigenous children... So it's a matter of gathering a lot of money and political influence to stomp out other religions, there is no philosophy involved. Using public schools to teach one scripture but no other is another typical approach, still used under the pressure of religions in various countries. Or outright denying education to children as the Taliban would do to girls.
A more peaceful phenomenon may be for religions to "learn from each other" in how to best keep the flock together and fighting materialism. Examples for such is religions improving conversion rates in new regions by incorporating local traditions and practices (labelled "pagan" for no good reason) into the church.

Yes, it all amounts to Psychology, not philosophy or 'religion'. It's humans being human.

Religion is the field of faith, not a subdomain of philosophy. Hence religion falls outside the domain where epistemological principles apply.

Sometimes the followers of two different religions acknowledge that
they cannot convince the opponent from the other side. Hence both
live in coexistence with their mutually incompatible worldviews.
But
history also shows many cases where the difference between
incompatible religions escalates in acts of violence.
It would be an illusory solution if both religions were watered down to the point where they say: We are both looking at the same phenomenon, just from different perspectives.


Just be careful not to try watering down Sodium.

@ScottRowe. In case my original point 3 was not correctly expressed in English: I changed my wording. - I am not a native speaker.

Sorry, I was just being silly. Your wording is always good. Sodium metal bursts into flame on contact with water. Some religions seem quite inflammatory.

So personally, I'd be tempted to throw strict classification to the wind in this case, because worldview clashes are pretty much on the very top of every "philosophical food chain" imaginable!  And so I believe we ought to look at individual criteria; because actually, I think many of the ones you cite for scientific theories work quite nicely here, with some additions and adaptions to their new environment.  I suspect this is because truth shares certain common essential features, whether it be scientific, spiritual, etc.  (Some religions will advocate absurdity as a strength, and I'll give my thoughts on that in point #3 below.)  For instance:

Falsifiability.  E.g., every time someone says, "The Bible can't be trusted because of scientific or historical flaws," then they are admitting, even if unintentionally, that the Bible is falsifiable.  And that's actually a good thing!  Because it means we can investigate; and when we find out that--whoops!--it was our lack of understanding, and that we had to "catch up" to the Bible, then that can be a more valuable piece of evidence for its reliability than if there were no perceived error in the first place.  Real-world history, and real-world and honest eyewitness testimony, is "messier" than fairy tales, usually requiring some "untangling" and investigation to fully understand.  But if a religion claims a text to be infallible, and yet it contains clear and obvious errors in matters of fact, that ought to be a serious dent in its reliability.
Predictive power.  I think this applies, with a couple tweaks/notes:
(A) Prophecy: This is predictive, but just tweaked, viewed as after-the-fact.  The predictive power here is a function of the prophecy preceding its fulfillment, its specificity, and its probability of being naturally predicted, given the conditions at the time.  If a religious prophecy is falsified and expired (past a promised timeframe), that is obviously a serious blow.
(B) Revelation: If it can reveal something about your heart that nothing else adequately does, that's a kind of "predictive" power in a way, just not as a function of time, but as a function of light: or, God proving that He knows what's hidden from others.  For instance, Paul says that if the secrets of a person's heart are made obvious, a person ought to take that very seriously as a matter of epistemology (I Corinthians 14:25; see, John 4:39).
Internal consistency.  I do believe this is very important.  John argues that "no lie is of the truth" (I John 2:21); that is, truth is coherent by nature.  That might sound overly simplistic, to go almost without saying--that is, until you've been in a philosophical discussion about worldviews!  As I understand it, some religions advocate that absurdity is a good thing.  Now, while advanced truth might be incomprehensible to finite creatures, this is not the same as blatant, clear absurdity in the natural realm.  At the least, absurdity cannot possibly be the grounds for believing something to be true, if using a logical epistemology of any sort, by very definition.  At best, it must be ignored in such comparisons, relegated to a separate realm altogether.  Allowing absurdity into a logical discussion does not shed any light, but rather, it brings a massive fog of darkness over the whole lot.  It must be self-evidently incoherent to argue why one absurdity should be intrinsically better than any other.
Parsimony.  I think this has some value, though a bit of caution could be that a lack of apparent coherence may be due to our limited understanding.  But it seems to me that detected coherence must indeed be a desirable trait.  The tighter the elegance of a system of thought, the more weight it has in this sense; and the more "ad hoc" the explanations, the less weight it has (even detrimental, if badly "contorted").  For instance, Paul argues that the entire Old Testament societal moral law is one single principle: "For all the law is fulfilled in one word, even in this; Thou shalt love thy neighbour as thyself."  That is, the societal moral law is like a single, beautiful diamond, changing its hue and sparkle when rotating its point of view, yet underneath, a coherent jewel.
Empirical support.  Similar to #1, #2.  I'd add that in some sense, empirical details are important in the way that trivia may be important in a witness's testimony in a court trial.  The witness claims that he was at the grocery store, purchased some Fruit Loops and milk between 5 and 5:30, before heading home, and on the way, saw the robbery.  What he planned to eat for breakfast the next morning is not particularly important on its own; yet even those details can become critical in a trial.  If he was lying about the Fruit Loops, maybe he was lying about the person he saw commit the robbery!  A source with a lot of scientific, historical, and otherwise empirical statements is a good thing when it proves honest, because it can lend to credibility for the areas where we cannot empirically verify it by the nature of the case.

Beyond that, I think there are a few other random epistemological tools.  For example, the Bible invites people to "taste and see that the LORD is good" (Psalm 34:8), which is an internal (subjective) challenge; and I think that internal evidence is perfectly valid here, even quite important.  Another tool would be the personal testimonies of others, weighted properly per your knowledge of them and their trustworthiness; the effects on a people's lives; even the effects on society as a whole (yet granting that societal effects can be like massive freight trains, enjoying benefits or suffering detriments of previous generations many times).  Another could be the seeming "honesty" of the source--whether it records even the flaws about its heroes in honest fashion, for instance.
And then I think there are some things which aren't properly tools, but sharpening files and lubricating oils.  There's the importance of the consistent practice of honesty, both in our internal thoughts and with others; because if we can lie to ourselves about the little things, how can we trust ourselves in the big things?  Jesus argued that a big enemy of "light" (which is a biblical term that references epistemology) is "evil," which broadly, includes any "rending" or "tearing" of something good, such as truth, moral goodness, or anything else.  Thus internal coherence (#3 above) is quite important, not only as an epistemological trait to look for, but a trait with which we must look if we will see clearly.  That seems almost self-evident when we say it, but it's something that I suspect we don't think about nearly enough.  Another epistemological "oil" that the Bible encourages as very important (e.g., Proverbs 2:1-5; Luke 11:10) is a fervent, persistent seeking of the truth with all the heart, with the same passion that one would exert to look for hid treasure; which makes a lot of sense, too, given the importance of the matter.

The question was about competing religions, and your answer only mentions one religion.

@tkruse - Peter only referenced in examples his own religion, but this was clearly meant to apply to religions and general world views, as the very first lines also state. As such all these points are perfectly valid - In fact, the first points are empirically valid when we look at the sociology and psychology of religious change. (E.g. people do leave sects when the prophesied events don't happen.)

I can only comment on what is written, not what was supposedly meant.

War has been a popular method, e.g. the Crusades, the fighting over the Sunni/Shia split, the Albigensian Crusade

The worst way imaginable.The most powerful ideology in the world has to completely take over and wipe out any and all forms of any previous thought patterns, morals and values held by anyone apart from their own.
Philosophy's main unknown is consciousness however, and it's very evident that consciousness is subjective,therefore there will always be differences in thought patterns that will lead to commonalities being found between peers and another uprising in a set of beliefs will spring to life. We would cease to be what we know as a human being if this becomes the case, we will effectively be meat robots.

From Conifold:

You should take your reflections to their logical conclusion. Religions are not scientific theories, so scientific standards are not appropriate, but they are not theories either, so why should "settling theoretical disagreements" be appropriate at all? They are ways of life that encompass traditions, culture, values, morality, etc., knowledge claims are subservient to that. It makes sense to settle disagreements within a shared way of life, as in science or politics, not across them. There is no "settling" when elements that make it meaningful are not shared. There is, at best, co-existence.


Then how would an impartial external observer select one religion among many? Or are you suggesting that they shouldn't select any of them (the problem is undecidable) or that they should select all of them (pluralism/co-existence)? To make an analogy with science, should we be pluralists about "Flat Earthism" and "Round Earthism"? (Not my downvote.)

Why would an impartial external observer even want to select one among many? That presumes that there is a preferred answer, and that it is valuable to find it. Many of us would disagree with one or both of those assumptions. Beware of assuming that what is important to your religious beliefs is important to anyone else.

@keshlam "Why would an impartial external observer even want to select one among many? That presumes that there is a preferred answer, and that it is valuable to find it" -  I think you forgot to carefully read the next sentence in my comment above: Or are you suggesting that they shouldn't select any of them (the problem is undecidable) or that they should select all of them (pluralism/co-existence)?

@keshlam It's perfectly fine to select an empty set. Now, regarding values, if a religion is true, do you really think that someone interested in finding truth wouldn't be interested to know? Of course, that presumes that the individual is interested in finding truth in the first place, but that's what philosophy is about, isn't it?

@user80226 another reason for not selecting any of the alternatives is because the person doesn't think the question is important to them. I walk by tons of stuff in stores without really noticing it, I'm not searching for those things. Many people might have already found what is important to them, so other people asking peripheral questions are just noise. I have a lot of ideas that I think would help people, but without some grounds for offering, I don't say anything. "Meet people where they are at", not where you want them to be.

@ScottRowe I'm reminded once again of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apatheism

@user80226 yes, I keep that idea in mind, thank you for it. But what about someone who has chosen views that are not on the question's list of alternatives? Would Nonduality make the list? Sometimes by asking, we find out that there is a better question, and completely different possibilities. I like the book, "The Art Of Possibility".

@ScottRowe In my earlier question https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/118294/80226 I quoted from SEP a definition of religion that's flexible enough to include mainstream religions such as Buddhism and Hinduism, which seem to encompass teachings that have some overlap with Nondualism. Buddhism in particular doesn't include a belief in God or gods, so that's probably a better example on the list that is close to what you are looking for.

Having an interest in truth does not necessarily mean one seeks answers to all possible questions, or believes that answers are possible for all questions. Do colorless green ideas sleep furiously? Why is a duck when it spins? Or, to stay closer to on topic, how many angels can dance on the head of a pin? ("Theoretically, as many as wish to. Practically, as many as will fit.") Sometimes the correct response is "that is not a meaningful question." Or, to put it in a single word, mu.  Anything I could accept as a deity would be too large for our belief to be accurate, or to matter.

@keshlam Sounds like you are an apatheist.

@user80226: I don't like the term, and I don't think it correctly captures the nuances of my beliefs, but if categorizing me that way is convenient for you, sure. (I usually describe my beliefs as strong agnostic theist, but I am not a philosopher and do not claim that I am using those terms properly.) It still remains true that it is possible to waste a lot of effort on constructing and answering philosophical questions which have absolutely no applicability to the real world, and I honestly believe that the question of Truth in religion is an inherent contradiction.

@keshlam I just asked this question that may interest you: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/118368/80226. Feel free to give it a shot.

"Then how would an impartial external observer select one religion among many? "--Harry Harrison explored this in The Streets of Ashkelon

The 'gods' originally had their own universe to operate in, unfortunately a random fluctuation of state via quantum tunneling blended those chaotically and they have had to pussy foot around since.
